# Ссылки с Font Awesome не работают

Tags: fontawesome

Делаю лендинг.
https://merrymaker14.github.io/portfolio

Но иконки из Font Awesome не отрабатывают ссылками.

```
<!-- Font Awesome -->
     <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
...
<div class="media">
<ul>
    <li>    
        <a target="_blank" class="btn btn-social-icon btn-vk" href="https://vk.com/merrymaker14">
            <span class="fa fa-vk"></span>
        </a>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
</div>
```

Почему? Пример по ссылке виден.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задайте для класса `media` свойство `z-index`:

```
.media {
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

Comment: Вы оказались правы, но хватило и значения "2", чтобы заработало :)